# Custom font in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, fonts, command-prompt

I am currently making a Text user interface/TUI in batch. I want the font in the command prompt (console) to be exactly the same as the default Windows font, and  I wish to do it without making registry changes. Is this possible?

(I can't give debug details right now, sorry about that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this website](https://www.howtogeek.com/716407/how-to-change-the-default-system-font-on-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Windows%2010%27s%20default%20system%20font,on%20your%20Windows%2010%20PC.) the default Windows 10 font is Segeo UI. I couldn't find a way to set this as the font used in the basic command prompt, as it seems to be restricted to a set amount of fonts, however the new Windows Terminal which can be downloaded from the Windows Store allows you to.

You simply press ctrl + , to open settings, go down to the Command Prompt profile on the left hand side, then go to appearance, and click show all fonts
[image: Image of Windows terminal appearance menu]

Once you've clicked that, open the fonts dropdown and you'll find Segeo UI in the menu

[image: Image showing list of fonts in terminal settings]

Then just click save, and job done!